# WinRT AppBar changing on context (or ignoring right click)?

Tags: windows-runtime, contextmenu, appbar

I am porting a Desktop WPF application to WinRT and I'm facing a little issue.

I had a ItemsControl and I had a context menu on every item to delete / edit the item.

I have been told that PopupMenu are not good in WinRT and I should use a AppBar.

I think I'm doing something wrong or I misunderstood that.

I thought that I could put that options on a AppBar and when I select an element, popup the bar and click where I need.

The problem is that the AppBar will show up when I right click on any part of my app, so that buttons will show up with an item selected.

So can I change the layout of the AppBar on different contexts (because it seems that Microsoft wants us to use AppBar as context menu without context capabilities) or only show it when I want via code?

Would be good to have a TopAppBar with some App-wide options and a BottomAppBar just for ListView's item context menu.

Or maybe I'm doing all this stuff wrong and I have to use another approach to put extra options on the Listview's items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking about this correctly. `AppBar` is the place where you should put all your non-essential and selection based commands.

The guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761499.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx) suggest that they should be arranged as follows:

- Navigation commands should be in `TopAppBar`
- Commands related to selection should on the left side of `BottomAppBar`
- The rest of page specific commands should be on the right side of `BottomAppBar`

Contextual commands should only be shown when a relevant item to that command is selected. For that purpose you should set `Visibility` of these commands accordingly. Also `AppBar` should open automatically when an item with contextual commands in it is selected. You can do that programmatically by setting its `IsOpen` property. You should also set it to sticky mode by via `IsSticky` property.

If you're using MVVM you can bind your viewmodel properties to all `Button` and `AppBar` properties mentioned above.

There's a `CustomAppBar` control available in [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/). I haven't used it myself yet but it has a couple of extra features that might prove useful in your case.